# CtrlList inserting item through postmessage treat notification

Tags: c++, winapi, postmessage, listctrl

So here is my problem, i have a `CtrlList`, and I want to insert items via `PostMessage` (asyncron) therefore the message `LVM_INSERT_MESSAGE`, is going to be  processed when it is his turn, but the problem is i need to allocate memory for `LVITEM`, so that i don't loose it before i insert the item. But after i loose the pointer to the allocated item after exiting the function. And since insert item creates another item, i find it hard to deallocate the memory i allocate for `LVITEM`.

My solution was since `LVM_INSERT_MESSAGE` sends `LVN_INSERT_MESSAGE` notification, on that notification to call a function, but the only way to get the lvitem is throw an lparam, but on_notify has (`NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult`) parameters. Can you give me a solution for deallocating that memory, i must insert it with postmessage, don't tell me to use send message or the function insertitem . Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post a custom message to some other window, and in its handler add the item then free memory.

If the list control is already subclassed, there is no need for other window and the message can be sent directly to the control.

Comment: Thank you, this is another idea to, but i put the allocated memory pointer into the lParam variable of the LVITEM structure, and after the LVN_INSERTITEM message is processed, it sends a notification, that i take and process by taking the last inserted item's lParam variable and deallocate the memory pointer that i stored there .